# Visual Studio Post Build Run Exe not running

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have a exe that creates/alters a file in the same directory as the exe. I can run this manually and it works. But i cannot get it to run as part of a post build event in visual studio.

Below is what is in the Post Build event box:
"$(ProjectDir)\WebSiteVersion\Versioner.exe"

I dont get any errors or exceptions but the file is never created in the directory.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify that the copy/create you are issuing through the exe has absolute path rather than relative for starters. Also check if the exe actually runs as a post build event by either seeing the logs or procmon.

Comment: the file copy was using the relative path for the file. Changed to Absolute and everything was ok. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Verific the path of your exe

in my project i added notepad.exe i it still work

maybe you are forgeting something in post-build event

well here my commands

```
copy "$(TargetDir)XXXXXX.exe" "$(SolutionDir)Deploy\"
notepad.exe
exit 0
```

Comment: I added the notepad.exe and exit(0) and the both fire. However it is still not executing the first exe.